# La possibilité même de la science mathématique semble une contradiction insoluble

Tags: mathématiques

> La possibilité même de la science mathématique semble une contradiction insoluble.

(Source: *Science and Hypothesis* by H. Poincaré)

In the above quotation how do you translate "science mathématique"? As *mathematical science* or *science of mathematics*?

Comment: More context would help figure out what he meant. It could be interpreted two ways with *mathématique* as a noun or as an adjective.

Comment: I'm not fluent in English, I can read it but I'm not able to give bilingual answer. I know, translation is an art, not only a grammar and dictionary problem ; and you will have to read and read again, and then you will feel mental structure of those two languages. From now you're are welcome... *Un francophone qui admire ceux qui se donnent la peine d'apprivoiser le français* :)

Comment: @Solver We don't necessarily answer in French. In fact, We use to answer in English when the question is in English, and French when the question is in French. The problem is when the answer is long, we may mis-translate in english, so it may contain errors, so it is safer if we explain complexe things in French. As you see, the long answer of cl-r is in french, and the short one of Stéphane is in English.

Answer (score 1):

La citation de votre question et la réponse à votre question sont dans *[cette page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophie_des_math%C3%A9matiques)*

La *science mathématique* dont parle Henri Poincaré est un terme utilisé par les *intuitionnistes* et par eux seuls.

La question qu'il pose trouve sa réponse :

> La question de savoir si *les mathématiques* sont ou non une science est une question relevant de **la philosophie des mathématiques**.

On parle ici, de philosophie *des mathématiques*, et non de philosophie *de la science mathématique* ; et dans toute la page on parle *des mathématiques*.

Il n'y a pas de science des mathématiques, la *science mathématique* est un terme lié à un courant de la philosophie des mathématiques, l'utilisation du terme est indissociable de ce contexte.

---

***Usage***

Durant tout le cursus scolaire et universitaire on enseigne *les mathématiques*, différenciant ainsi la géométrie, l'algèbre, la trigonométrie...

Partout ailleurs, on utilise *les mathématiques* et non la science mathématique, toutefois certains matheux de bon niveau utilisent le terme [*La Mathématique*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math%C3%A9matiques) :

> Le singulier (« *la mathématique* ») est parfois employé en français, mais « le mot donne alors au contexte une teinte d'archaïsme ou de didactisme ».
> Toutefois, certains auteurs, à la suite de Nicolas Bourbaki, insistent sur l'utilisation du singulier, pour montrer l'uniformisation apportée par l'approche axiomatique contemporaine : Jean Dieudonné semble être le premier à avoir lancé ce mot d'ordre :
>    « *La Mathématique* est une » ; le vaste traité de Bourbaki s'intitule *Éléments **de mathématique***, tandis que, par contraste, le fascicule historique qui l'accompagne a pour titre *Éléments d'histoire des mathématiques*.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean both.

*La science mathématique* could mean just “math” (it flows better as such in this sentence), however the more common term to refer to this particular science is “les mathématiques”.

It is subject to intepretation, but Poincaré's intent was probably to include slightly more than math, that is, science based on mathematics, which you might allude to as “mathematical science”. If I had to, I'd rather choose this one as a translation, but it's rather unclear from this single sentence.

Comment: Don't worry, it is usual to get this type of interaction. It is not easy to formulate the question in a way people will know exactly what you are after. We can always ask clarification questions in response...